# Rails: is it safe to do this in a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, security

I have a model `tag` with attribute `title (string)`.

A `tag` belongs_to a model `document` with a `has_many :throught` association.

In document#show view, I need to show all tags associated to that document, so I do:

```
%p= raw @document.tags.map{|t| link_to t.title.prepend('#'), t}.join(', ')
```

Is this safe considering that a user can be able to create a tag ?

If it's not safe, how can I achieve the same result?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the tag's title will be escaped before becoming the content of the link, so even if there were HTML in it, it would be rendered, not output raw. What *will* be output without escaping here is the string resulting from the `join`, which is fine.

Answer (score 0):

In general, all logic (or as much as possible) should be moved to helpers or models. I wouldn't say this is "safe" or "not safe", but in general good practice to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it is safe as the `link_to` will escape its argument, but why take the risk (maybe the inside of the block will be modified in a few months, etc...), use `safe_join`:

```
%p= safe_join @document.tags.map{|t| link_to t.title.prepend('#'), t}, ', '
```

Or use my [`rails_join`](https://github.com/marcandre/rails_join) "gem" and you can do your `join` safely without needing the `raw`.